# Removing an item from a ListBox with MVVM

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, mvvm-light, windows-phone-7.1.1

I'm trying to remove an item from a ListBox. The command is properly fired and the item is correctly removed from the database but the list is not refreshed.

Here is the ViewModel. I'm using MVVM Light 4.1

```
public class ViewAllViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ViewAllViewModel()
    {
        NavigateToAddNew = new RelayCommand(() => NavigationController<Views>.Current.NavigateTo(Views.AddNew));
        Remove = new RelayCommand<int>(DeleteMeasure);

        using (var repository = App.ServiceLocator.Get<IRepository>())
        {
            Measures = new ObservableCollection<Measure>(repository.Measures);
        }
    }

    private void DeleteMeasure(int measureId)
    {
        Measure measure;

        using (IRepository repository = App.ServiceLocator.Get<IRepository>())
        {
            measure = repository.Measures.Single(m => m.Id == measureId);
            repository.Measures.Delete(measure);
            repository.SaveChanges();
        }

        measure = Measures.Single(m => m.Id == measureId);
        if (Measures.Remove(measure))
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Measures);
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand NavigateToAddNew { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand<int> Remove { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<Measure> _measures;
    public ObservableCollection<Measure> Measures
    {
        get { return _measures; }
        set { Set(() => Measures, ref _measures, value); }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

PS: I know there are similar questions but none of the accepted answers worked for me :(

**EDIT 1**
This is the code I use in the XAML page to bind the ListBox to the list of items:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding Path=Measures}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

here is the binding of the ViewModel to the main container

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=ViewAll}" x:Name="LayoutRoot" />
```

**EDIT 2**
This is the full code of the ViewModel

```
public class ViewAllViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ViewAllViewModel()
    {
        NavigateToAddNew = new RelayCommand(() => NavigationController<Views>.Current.NavigateTo(Views.AddNew));
        Remove = new RelayCommand<int>(DeleteMeasure);

        LoadMeasures();

        Messenger.Default.Register<PropertyChangedMessage<ObservableCollection<Measure>>>(this, message => LoadMeasures());
    }

    private void LoadMeasures()
    {
        using (var repository = App.ServiceLocator.Get<IRepository>())
        {
            Measures = new ObservableCollection<Measure>(repository.Measures.OrderByDescending(m => m.MeasureDate).ThenByDescending(m => m.Id).Take(20));
        }
    }

    private void DeleteMeasure(int measureId)
    {
        Measure measure;

        using (IRepository repository = App.ServiceLocator.Get<IRepository>())
        {
            measure = repository.Measures.Single(m => m.Id == measureId);
            repository.Measures.Delete(measure);
            repository.SaveChanges();
        }

        measure = Measures.Single(m => m.Id == measureId);
        Measures.Remove(measure);

        RaisePropertyChanged("LastMeasure", null, measure, true);
    }

    public RelayCommand NavigateToAddNew { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand<int> Remove { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<Measure> _measures;
    public ObservableCollection<Measure> Measures
    {
        get { return _measures; }
        set { Set(() => Measures, ref _measures, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does Measures.Remove(measure) return true? do you see your Measures getter fire again after the RaisePropertyChanged line?

Comment: Can you show the code that is binding `ListBox.ItemsSource` to `Measures`? The only thing I can think of is something wrong with the binding. (Also, you shouldn't need to `RaisePropertyChanged` on the `Measures` collection after removing an item. The `ObservableCollection` automatically raises a `CollectionChanged` event when an item is removed, and will update the binding)

Comment: I will as soon as I get home :)

Comment: for @Rachel: I finally managed to add the requested code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything obviously wrong. All I can suggest is to try simplifying your `ListBox` to just this:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Measures}" />
```

And remove the code that calls `RaisePropertyChanged(() => Measures);` (since it should not be needed).

If neither of those work, I would test to see what happens if you completely reset your `Measures` property, as in:

```
private void DeleteMeasure(int measureId)
{
    using (IRepository repository = App.ServiceLocator.Get<IRepository>())
    {
        var measure = repository.Measures.Single(m => m.Id == measureId);
        repository.Measures.Delete(measure);
        repository.SaveChanges();
    }

    Measures = repository.Measures;
}
```

If that causes a successful refresh of the `ListBox`, it would imply that something is going on with the `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: It didn't work :S
I added the full code of the VM in the body of the question.